# SQL Subquery (error while using where and order by clause)

Tags: sql

```
with t as (
    Select (S0.Docdate)
    from OINM S0
    where ( S0.Docdate >= ('2001-03-03'))
    order by S0.Docdate asc
) 
Select (S0.Docdate)
from OINM S0
```

Comment: That ORDER BY makes no sense. Put it last at main level instead.

Comment: Please write what you are trying to do exactly and give a brief description in the post.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` should be used at the end of a query.